# How to convert the string variable to JSON object in Azure DevOps YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm using the azure devops classic pipeline to deploy the ADF. I've defined the variables in and some of them are of JSON object , whenever I try to fetch the  variable it will be of string type.
And my deployments will fail.
Like in the below code I try to use the variable **trigger_time** using $(trigger_time) but this will be string.

```
variables:
  pipeline_name: 'TEST-ADF'
  trigger_time: '{"minutes":[10],"hours":[18]}'

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: '...................'
    subscriptionId: '.................'
    resourceGroupName: '....................'
    location: 'West Europe'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ENA Management Reporting Platform/..............'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ENA Management Reporting Platform/..........................'
    
    overrideParameters: '-factoryName $(pipeline_name) -triggerRecurrance $(trigger_time) .....................'
    deploymentName: 'POC_ADF'
```

I also tried to convert the variable using **${{ convertToJson(trigger_time) }}**, but it isnot able to do so.